# HttpClient.SendAsync method exits without throwing exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpclient

I am calling the following function to get access token for retrieving Twitter user profile using REST Api.

```
  public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        try
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token ");
            var customerInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(OAuthConsumerKey + ":" + OAuthConsumerSecret));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + customerInfo);
            request.Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //program exits at this point 
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
            return item["access_token"];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("In  Retrieving access token : " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

The program exits/terminates without retrieving a response at the point `HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);` is called.

This is the parent function which calls **GetAccessToken()**

```
public async Task getUserProfile(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (accessToken == null)
            {
                accessToken = await GetAccessToken().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format(" https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name={0}", userName));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic jsonObj = serializer.Deserialize<object>(jsonString);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (DEBUG)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("In  Retrieving user profile from twitter : " + ex.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
```

I am unable to catch an exception as to why the program exits at GetAccessToken() or getUserProfile(). But the code executes successfully and retrieves an HttpResponseMessage if getUserProfile() has `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` as return type. Why does this problem occur? How can the exception be caught?

Comment: As you said, your method is asynchronous... the exception will occurs when the task will be executed/completed. Do you require to use an async method or not?

Comment: Can you show the code calling `getUserProfile`? What type of application is this?

Comment: Wonder why you're using JavaScriptSerializer there?  Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer) on that says "Json.NET should be used [for] serialization and deserialization. Provides serialization and deserialization functionality _for AJAX-enabled applications_."

Comment: @Paulo Morgado  getUserProfile() is called using function                                           `public void getTwitterInfo()
        {
            var twitter = new Twitter("consumerKey","consumerSecret");
            twitter.getUserProfile(userName);

        }`

Comment: So, you're not waiting for it to finish. Is it a console application?

Comment: @Paulo Morgado  . No it is a wpf application

Comment: Why do you have `.ConfigureAwait(false)` after the call? That might be causing it to lose it's context (which means the app might close before the response comes back).

Answer (score 5):

Your application exits permaturely because you are not waiting for `getUserProfile()` to be completed. You can mark `getTwitterInfo` as async similar to the others or tell it to wait for the task to finish

```
public async Task getTwitterInfo() { 
    var twitter = new Twitter("consumerKey","consumerSecret");
    await twitter.getUserProfile(userName); 
}
```

OR

```
public void getTwitterInfo() { 
    var twitter = new Twitter("consumerKey","consumerSecret");
    var task = twitter.getUserProfile(userName); 
    var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I too identified the problem and solved it like this                           ` var userProfile= twitter.getUserProfile(userName).Result() `

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

I have the same problem in my own code and this seems to have fixed it, should be equivalent to the original call. I still don't understand the root cause of the crash, though.

Comment: You SHOULD not use .Result because it's [evil](https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d)!

Comment: This is weird. I have the exact same issue. After upgrading to .NET 8 my HTTP requests had this method exiting behavior without throwing. Removing await and adding .Result as you suggested seemed to solve it. Really wonder what is going on here